# OpenERP 7.0 Client and Server Errors

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

I'm a new user of OpenERP 7.0 and PostgresSQL (windows platform)

I have recently migrate our OpenERP 7.0 to new machine. I just backed-up PostgreSQL database and restored its backup into new server after installing PostgreSQL 9.2 and OpenERP 7.0.

I can access the localhost:8069 and login into our OpenERP, but as soon as I login, I got OpenERP client Error and if I click on any other option i got Server Errors:

I have attached two screenshots of both Errors, I am not sure do I need to install or copy anything else from old server to new server to make OpenERP optional as it is working  on old windows machine?

in Settings Menu, I also can not see any installed modules, if we backup database from older machine to newer machine, do we need to reinstall all the modules or it will automatically restored with backup?

I will appreciate your help and support please!

Thanks & regards

[OpenERP Client Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRhMC.jpg)

[Server Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0ULs.jpg)

Comment: Check your *addons-path* It seems like addons-path missing when you start your OpenERP server.

Answer (score 0):

Your **openerp-server.conf** file need addons path.

### Changing the addons-path of openerp-server.conf

1. Go to the openerp-7 folder under program files or program files (x86)
   => C:\Program Files (x86)\openerp-7.0\server\ like that.
2. open and edit the **openerp-server.conf** file under **server** folder.
3. In the openerp-server.conf, find the **addons_path =**
4. copy your extra addons path and paste it like that.

addons_path = C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo-8\server\openerp\addons,**D:\Development Place\IBIZ\Team Lead\odoo8 workspace\Clinic\ext-addons**

5. this my openerp-server.conf addons_path.
6. make your openerp-server.conf addons-path like that.